# $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-2)^{n+1}}{x^n}$ for which values of $x\neq 0$ does the series converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-2)^{n+1}}{x^n}$$

for which values of $x\neq 0$ does the series converge?

I cannot apply the ratio test because the general term of the series is not going to $>0, <0$ eventually (on its taill)

And I observe that If $x>0$  or $x<0$ only the alternating parity is changin $+$ tersm becomes $-$ and vice versa and it doesnot effects the convergence

so I want to appy alternating series test and if $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{(-2)^{n+1}}{x^n}<\infty$$ then $x$ must be absolute value less than 1

so $|x|<1$ is the solution?

How can I show it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Ratio test for absolute convergence ..

Here $$\{a_n\}=\frac {(-2)^{n+1}}{x^n}$$
Then$$\lim_{n \to \infty } |\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}|=\lim_{n \to \infty } |\frac {2}{|x|}=\frac{2}{|x|}$$
For convergence $\frac{2}{|x|}\lt 1$

The given series converges for $|x|\gt 2$

Comment: @Nimu Basak: The series converges for $|x|>2.$

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the series as
$$-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(-\frac2x\right)^n$$
This is a geometric series and will converge iff $|-2/x|<1$ iff $|x|>2$.

If the series converges, its sum is $\frac4{x+2}$.

Comment: I want to rewrite it also in power series form as $1/x=y$, can I see this is a power series also?

Comment: @Jale'dejaleuffnejale I don't get what you say. I have added the sum of this series.

Comment: @Jale'dejaleuffnejale ...also, what is $y$?

Comment: I want to see the series as an power series? can we do it

Comment: I think without saying it I can say the radius of convergence right? it is infinity?

Comment: @Jale'dejaleuffnejale It already is a power series... in $-2/x$.

Comment: @Jale'dejaleuffnejale If you say this is a power series in $-2/x$, the radius of convergence is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

If I am right, you know that

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}(-2)^{n+1}t^n$$ converges for $|t|<\dfrac12$.

Then your series converges for

$$\left|\frac1 x\right|<\frac12.$$